# How can I mock just for a non-null value?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Let's say I'm testing following method.

```java
/**
 * Does something. This method throws a {@code NullPointerException}
 * either given string or specified charset is {@code null}.
 * @param s the string
 * @param c the charset
 */
void doSomething(String s, Charset c) {
}
```

How, when I test, can I make mock for a non-null purpose?

```java
assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,
             new MyObject().doSomething(null, UTF_8));
assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,
             new MyObject().doSomething("", null));
```

Is there any libraries/methods for mocking a general non-null value?

I tried `Mockito.mock` and it seems throw an Exception for some invalid types for it can actually mock.

**Update**

By user2004685's answer, now, I'm curious if I can use `anyString` or `any(Class)` like this.

```java
assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,
             new MyObject().doSomething(null, any(Charset.class)));
assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,
             new MyObject().doSomething(anyString(), null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `void` method. If you are mocking it using Mockito to throw the Exception then you need to do something like this:

```
 Mockito.doThrow(new NullPointerException("Description"))
     .when(mymock)
     .doSomething(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Charset.class));
```

It should work even if `null` is passed to the method.

Comment: Can it make any sense if I use `anyString` or `any(Charset.class)` for `""` and `UTF_8`?

Comment: You can use `anyString()` if you want Mockito to process the mock for any String entered. If you want it for selected values then you can have a look at `Matchers` Class and use something like `Matchers.eq("...")`. Also, you can verify if the mock is invoked for the given values using `Mockito.verify()`.